# Chart.js - The types of 'options.legend.position' are incompatible between these types

Tags: typescript, graph, charts, legend

I want to put the legend under the graphic (what is quite simple), but the code doesn't work at all, giving me the following error:

```
The types of 'options.legend.position' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"bottom" | "left" | "right" | "top" | "chartArea" | undefined'.
```

Worse still, I got the same code in CodeSandBox, without any difference, and it works well...Here's the link to it: https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-hill-3nme9?file=/src/components/Scatter.tsx

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Setting position as const worked for me

```
options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: "bottom" as const, // <----
                labels: {
                    fontColor: "#000080"
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: can someone explain why this works?

Comment: @Miguel my guess is that when you type just "bottom", it counts it as a plain string and not one of '"bottom" | "left" | "right" | "top" | "chartArea" | undefined'. I found an answer to a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66953323/12532248

Answer (score 2):

```
{
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            // position: 'top'
            position: 'left' as 'left'
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Present device comparison'
        }
    }
}
```

It needs to tell as type.

Answer (score 0):

The [scatter](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html) chart expects the data to be passed as an array of objects containing x and y properties each. Given your data, you could change the chart type into a line chart by defining `type: "line"` and adding `showLine: false` to each dataset.

```
const chartConfig = {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: "Bar Dataset",
      data: [10, 20, 30, 40],
      showLine: false
    },
    {
      label: "Line Dataset",
      data: [50, 50, 50, 50],
      type: "line",
      showLine: false
    }
```

Please take a look at your amended [**Sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-darwin-oy1cn?file=/src/components/Scatter.tsx).