# Why property type unassignalbe while passing via const in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I know this is 100% a noob question, but i can't handle myself and want to know an answer.

```
type SweetAlertPosition =
    'top' | 'top-start' | 'top-end' | 'top-left' | 'top-right' |
    'center' | 'center-start' | 'center-end' | 'center-left' | 'center-right' |
    'bottom' | 'bottom-start' | 'bottom-end' | 'bottom-left' | 'bottom-right';
```

Main interface(simplified):

```
interface SweetAlertOptions {
    ...,
    position?: SweetAlertPosition
}
```

```
class Swal {
    mixin(options: SweetAlertOptions)
}
```

Now, if i explicitly pass options to .mixin call: **Swal.mixin({ position: 'bottom' })** - no error is there.
But if i predefine options in some const object:

```
defaultOptions = {
   position: 'bottom'
}
```

Passing now make an error - **Swal.mixin(defauiltOptions)**

```
Types of property 'position' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"top" | "top-start" | "top-end" | "top-left" | "top-right" | "center" | "center-start" | "center-end" | "center-left" | "center-right" | "bottom" | "bottom-start" | "bottom-end" | "bottom-left" | "bottom-right" | undefined'.
```

I already found out that a have to cast String type to const:

```
defaultOptions = {
    position: 'botton' as const | as SweetAlertPosition
}
```

**But why passing options via const obj(defaultOptions) make position property become String-type, and passing it directly does not oO ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring a `const` variable, its type is derived only from the value you assign to it, not from where the variable is used (full type inference). When initialising a variable with an object literal, the property types are [widened](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/literal-type-widening-in-typescript) so that you might assing other strings or numbers to them - unless you narrow them with `as const`.

When passing an object literal as an argument, its type is inferred from the parameter types of the called function.

In your case, I wouldn't write `as const` but recommend

```
const defaultOptions: SweetAlertOptions = {
   position: 'bottom'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `defaultOptions` has a type of `{ position: string }` unless you do something about it, like this:

```
const defaultOptions: SweetAlertOptions = {
   position: 'bottom'
}
```

Here, we explicitly declare that `defaultOptions` is of type `SweetAlertOptions` and then there is no error when passing into `mixin`.

In the example of passing in the value explicitly, the compiler can interpret the object in the context of the call.

Example in [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg7hCwCCAbCAnYAFA9gZwEthDcA7KAXgFgAoKBqAcmFzCagB9nWwBafMACGWDtxZs+EMgBMxPSegBmweRP4ZCAcwAWqrnUbMAxtOCY1psuYwDhoribOYpsy89vL94qzb6bdb0NGJgAjXGBWAFs1cMjcKLsRb2Y46Nc5RzCI9K9YnIT-bT0mAG46OkJrTCUhU1gEJDRMYAB5MBJyfCgAb2CGMAJiUjIAfgAuBsQUdCw8Ik6yOgBfCtpjLuAoGQhagFdUNo6R-En4aeasdsXuyl7+wYWRyez4mJXy2jpjVCF8bvgQlQ93ojCihAAHlUABRsG5nRozFrXE4ASl6q1omO+myg+DgQKoUDIEDgDSB0NRn3xQIAdOCoWRoTt9ocUV0qUA)